# Divide Set into pairs of elements with minimum difference between these elements

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, partitioning

I need an algorithm which can help me  divide **N-elements array** into **pairs**, **elements in each pair** must have **minimum difference**

Comment: Visit [Partition Problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/partition-a-set-into-two-subsets-such-that-the-difference-of-subset-sums-is-minimum/)

Comment: Do you mean to make the sum of the differences in each pair minimal? We need just one number to optimize for. Furthermore, must N be even?

Comment: I have an array of N values: {123456, 123455, 23401, 432516, 23333, 21009, ... }; I need to divide it into pairs, each pair contains 2 elements from array with minimum difference between it elements. For example, for array {123456, 123455, 23401, 23333} we can define pairs: [123456, 123455] and [23401, 23333]; N can be not even too

Comment: I conjecture the best solution is to sort the array and then cut off pairs.

Comment: What happens with the one left over element if N is odd?

Comment: _>> I conjecture the best solution is to sort the array and then cut off pairs._ Yes, I also think about this, but I hope that best solution exists. _>> What happens with the one left over element if N is odd?_ This element leaves without pair

Comment: Odd N is more interesting, You get different results depending on which element you leave out.

Comment: But how it can be different, if for example I did descent sort at all values in array, and grouped them in pairs?? It always be the same, the smallest value in array, doesn't it?

Comment: For example {1,2,5}: it is better to take the pair (1,2) instead of (2,5).

Comment: How do you think, does the way to avoid it exist?

Answer (score 0):

So, I assume that we may throw away at most 1 element (in case when *N* is odd). Let *a*<sub>1</sub> ≤ *a*<sub>2</sub> ≤ … ≤ *a*<sub>N</sub> be our set of numbers sorted in non-decreasing order. Let *f*(*k*) be the minimum possible sum of differences inside pairs formed by the first *k* numbers. (So minimum is taken over all partitions of the first *k* numbers into pairs.) As it is mentioned in comments for even *N* we just need to take elements one by one. Then

*f*(0) = *f*(1) = 0,

*f*(2·*k*) = *f*(2·*k* − 2) + (*a*<sub>2·*k*</sub> − *a*<sub>2·*k* − 1</sub>) for *k* ≥ 1 and

*f*(2·*k* + 1) = min { *f*(2·*k*)*, f*(2·*k* − 1) + (*a*<sub>2·*k* + 1</sub> − *a*<sub>2·*k*</sub>) } for *k* ≥ 1.

The last formula means that we can either throw away (2·*k* + 1)th element or throw away one element among the first (2·*k* − 1). On the remaining 2·*k* elements we apply known solution for even *N*.

This is a way to find numerical answer for the problem in O(*N*) time after sorting numbers, i. e. in general it takes O(*N* log *N*) time. After that if you need partition of all numbers into pairs just use backward step of dynamic programming. For even *N* just make pairs trivially. For odd *N* throw away *a*<sub>*N*</sub> if *f*(*N*) = *f*(*N* − 1) or take pair (*a*<sub>*N*</sub>, *a*<sub>*N* − 1</sub>) and decrease *N* by 2 otherwise.